# How to version assemblies—pre-build—based on work items

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

I'd like to automatically increment my assembly versions based on this ruleset:

1. Revision is always `0`
2. Build is incremented when the only WIT in the release is a Bug fix
3. Minor is incremented when the release contains any WIT other than a Bug fix; Build is then always set to `0`
4. Major is never automatically incremented

Naturally this will require a build step that can interact in some way with the project.

My first thought was to build a small Windows Service that utilizes the TFS SDK to construct the version number based on these rules and return it via a WCF call, etc. But I run into a problem there with a business requirement that all code and functionality must be replicated into a VSTS project as well (the customer owns the code and must be able to proceed without me). There's no installing such a service there, of course.

I then considered installing the service on *his* server, in turn making it available to VSTS. This would pass the [Rube Goldberg](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qybUFnY7Y8w) test with flying colors.

Is there an easier way of accomplishing this task? One that can work in both environments?

**EDIT**

I found [this](http://blog.majcica.com/2015/11/15/powershell-tips-and-tricks-retrieving-tfs-collections-and-projects/), but it's doubtful that the TFS SDK is registered in the GAC for VSTS.

Can someone confirm? Is the TFS SDK available to build scripts running on VSTS?

Comment: Can you edit the tag so it is clear to which version the answer applies? Is it TFS2015, VSTS, both, other?

Comment: @GiulioVian: Done, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well now that didn't take long.

I found [this](http://www.mercurynewmedia.com/blog/mercury-new-media-blog/2015/12/03/powershell-vso-rest-api-and-vnext-builds) and [this](http://blog.nwcadence.com/vststfs-rest-api-the-basics-and-working-with-builds-and-releases/) for using PowerShell to query the REST API. No GAC/SDK needed.

-- **EDIT** -----------------

I've intentionally excluded content from the pages behind these links as the solutions provided are exceedingly complex; it's not possible to cover the concepts here in a single post. In case the pages disappear or the URLs change, here are the links at archive.org:

> [1. PowerShell and vNext Builds](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/*/http://www.mercurynewmedia.com/blog/mercury-new-media-blog/2015/12/03/powershell-vso-rest-api-and-vnext-builds)
>   [2. VSTS/TFS REST API: The basics and working with builds and releases](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/*/http://blog.nwcadence.com/vststfs-rest-api-the-basics-and-working-with-builds-and-releases)

In any case, the concept is popular and well-covered—in the event these two become inaccessible, there are many others available on the same subject matter. As quickly as I found these, someone could find more.

Comment: I'd suspect because your answer contains 2 links, but doesn't copy the relevant content from those links to the answer. Blogs and other websites tend to change, disappear and break over time, which would make your answer worthless in its current state.

Comment: The TFS Object Model is no longer available in the GAC, but is can be downloaded from Nuget quite easily. Either as part of your build or included in a custom build extension. It's also available as part of the build agent itself, though the recommendation is to rely on your own copy. See: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib/blob/master/powershell/Docs/UsingOM.md

Comment: @jessehouwing: "I'd suspect because..." Good point. That issue crossed my mind when I posted, but I declined to include content for the reason I indicated in my edit just now. I suppose I'd have done well to state so then.

Comment: @jessehouwing: "The TFS Object Model..." Appreciate the update. FYI in the meantime I've decided to go with a date-based version numbering scheme: [year].[month].[day].[revision]. It's easier, cleaner, better for the user...  no muss, no fuss.

Comment: Yeah. that is much easier. That or using Git SemVer and putting the right tags on branches.

Comment: @jessehouwing: I looked at SemVer; dates won out for simplicity. I may look again.